# String Formatting using many pandas columns to create a new one

Tags: python, string, pandas, formatting

I would like to create a new columns in a pandas DataFrame just like I would do using a python f-Strings or format function.
Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"str": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
                   "int": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

print(df)

  str  int
0   a    1
1   b    2
2   c    3
3   d    4
4   e    5
```

I would like to obtain:

```
  str  int concat
0   a    1   a-01
1   b    2   b-02
2   c    3   c-03
3   d    4   d-04
4   e    5   e-05
```

So something like:

```
concat = f"{str}-{int:02d}"
```

but directly with elements of pandas columns. I imagine the solution is using pandas map, apply, agg but nothing successful.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: `df["concat"] = df["str"]+"-"+(df["int"].astype(str).str.zfill(2))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use lsit comprehension with `f-string`s:

```
df['concat'] = [f"{a}-{b:02d}" for a, b in zip(df['str'], df['int'])]
```

Or is possible use `apply`:

```
df['concat'] = df.apply(lambda x: f"{x['str']}-{x['int']:02d}", axis=1)
```

Or solution from comments with [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df["concat"] = df["str"] + "-" + df["int"].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

---

```
print (df)
  str  int concat
0   a    1   a-01
1   b    2   b-02
2   c    3   c-03
3   d    4   d-04
4   e    5   e-05
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build the concat column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"str": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
                   "int": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

df['concat'] = [f"{s}-{i:02d}" for s, i in df[['str', 'int']].values]

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  str  int concat
0   a    1   a-01
1   b    2   b-02
2   c    3   c-03
3   d    4   d-04
4   e    5   e-05
```

Answer (score 2):

I also just discovered that array indexing work on DataFrame columns

```
df["concat"] = df.apply(lambda x: f"{x[0]}-{x[1]:02d}", axis=1)

print(df)

  str  int concat
0   a    1   a-01
1   b    2   b-02
2   c    3   c-03
3   d    4   d-04
4   e    5   e-05
```

looks very sleek

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas' [string concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) method :

```
df['concat'] = df['str'].str.cat(df['int'].astype(str),sep='-0')

    str int concat
0   a   1   a-01
1   b   2   b-02
2   c   3   c-03
3   d   4   d-04
4   e   5   e-05
```